# How to count inPickup port of Pickup block from PML in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to calculate a KPI using the following formula `dataset.add(pickup.out.count()*pickup.inPickup.count())`

But I noticed `pickup.inPickup.count()` is returning 0 every time. Is there a way around for this?

Comment: Well, are you sure you want the `inPickup` port and not the `in` port? If yes, does the small visual counter next to `inPickup` show anything else but 0 at runtime?

Comment: (in other words: it is very likely not a buggy `pickup.inPickup.count()` method but the way you use it that is wrong. Consider adding some more details to help us help you